# How to parse the csv to hashmap grouping by column using opencsv

Tags: java, hashmap, opencsv

I am trying to use hashmap the col1 values to col2 values from a csv file using CSVREADER. But I am unable to find a logic to do so.

I want to do it through reading the CSV through CSVReader, looping the datalines and using arraylist and hashmap key and value(arraylist). I dont want to hardcode it..

I did something till the following. Unable to proceed further. Please help..

```
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),',','"',1);
        Map<String, List<String>> tableandcols = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> tablenames = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> colnames = new ArrayList<>();
        while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            tablenames.add(row[0]);
            colnames.add(row[1]);
            }

input data: 
State,City,Country
NJ,Trenton,US
NJ,Newark,US
NC,Cary,US
NC,Charlotte,US
GA,Atlanta,US

I want the data to be in hashmap as following
[<NJ,[Trenton,Newark]>
<NC,[Cary,Charlotte]>
<GA,[Atlanta]>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below piece of code :

```
    try
    {
      CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),',','"',1);
      Map<String, List<String>> tableandcols = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null) 
      {
        // If map contains state already, add the city to the values list
        if(tableandcols.containsKey(row[0]))
         { 
           tableandcols.get(row[0]).add(row[1);
         }
         // if map doesn't have this state as key, insert a key and value
         else {
           List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
           cities.add(row[1]);
           tableandcols.put(row[0], cities);
         }
      }
     } 
     catch(Exception e){
      // log exception
     }
```

Alternatively, you can also use [HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy.html) to map column values to java bean. Loop through the java beans list and aggregate cities based on state.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by using java-8 stream approach, use [readAll](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#readAll--) to read complete file in `List<String[]>`

> Reads the entire file into a List with each element being a String[] of tokens. Since the current implementation returns a LinkedList, you are strongly discouraged from using index-based access methods to get at items in the list. Instead, iterate over the list.

If you want to skip first row with headers then use `skip(1)`, and then use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors) to group the elements based on `State`

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = arr.stream().skip(1)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str[0], Collectors.mapping(str -> str[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Or simple `for` loop using [map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
List<String[]> arr = csvReader.readAll();

Map<String, List<String>> tableandcols = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for(String[] array : arr) {
    tableandcols.compute(array[0], (key,val)->val==null ? new ArrayList<>() : val).add(array[1]);
}
```